# convert the shell output to float64?

Tags: shell, go

i am using shell with golang to access apache log file and get some data. first i used to write output to the file directly and it was working, but now i need to get the output and use it in the program directly. and also i need to convert it to float64. i tried converting it into a string and then to float64, but it is not working?

```
func Mem_usage_data(j int) (Mem_predict float64, err error) {
    awkPart := fmt.Sprintf("awk '{print $%d/1024}'", j)

    out1, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "tail -n 1 /var/log/apache2/access.log| "+awkPart+" ").Output()
    fmt.Println("memory usage is", out1)
    s1 := string(out1)
    v1, err1 := strconv.ParseFloat(s1, 64)
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return v1, err
}
```

when i print the out1 i get something like this [48 46 49 50 48 49 49 55 10]. CAn you please help how to get the exact output in out1 and how to convert it into float64?

Comment: Try fmt.Println("memory usage is",string(out1))

Comment: Why on earth would one use Bash and awk like this?! There’s nothing they do that Go can’t do (more efficiently and portably)!

Answer (score 2):

The conversion fails probably because there is some whitespace or newline character on `s1`. Try to trim it first before doing the conversion. Use `strings.TrimSpace()` to achieve that.

```golang
v1, err1 := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.TrimSpace(s1), 64)
```